# oracle form and reports installation

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I try to install oracle forms and reports when i click on setup and installation begin but when i click on forms and deployment it shows this error

```
Unable to find dependent feature sets for the selected installation type "Forms and Reports Deployment". Please select a valid installation type.
Select a different install type or provide a different Oracle Home having all dependencies. Check http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=fmw122100&id=installhome for details about compatible products and install types.
```

check this picture
[image](http://oi65.tinypic.com/2hi40g8.jpg)

i try to download another but i did not find it . any help please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing it on top of Weblogic, make sure you have installed

- A Valid JDK for your machine (32 or 64 bit)
- A Weblogic 12c (infrastructure)
- When you are going to install forms/reports, point it to the Oracle_home which contains the WL infrastructure install.

On Oracle forums, [people say](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3819569?start=0&tstart=0) it works for them.

Comment: i download from this link    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/downloads/index.html        "Oracle Forms and Reports 12c (12.2.1.0) for Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit) Download".....     means before download oracle forms & reports we should download this weblogic?